# Expressjs server address host returns nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Following the standard ExpressJs hello word example, i get a host of ' : : '.

Why does this happen?

hello word example:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

I found a tip that was add 'localhost' after port parameter. It solved when i was looking just my pc, but it wont work over the network. What should i do?

Comment: Do you try this from the docs? http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: @LucasCosta Yes, i did.

Comment: I got exactly the same issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this already? I could swear it worked fine a few days ago...

Comment: @Jake sorry for longe time no answer! No, i didnt yet!

Answer (score 11):

For the code

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
```

without an address parameter in the `listen` function, Node will bind it to *any address*, related to the address `0.0.0.0` of IPV4, and corresponding to `::` in [`IPV6`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address). And this `IPv6` unspecified address, `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`, is reduced to `::`,

After running `netstat -a`

```
 TCP    [::]:3000              CP-Q10001:0       LISTENING
```

We know the node server listen on address `::` with port `3000`.

---

Refer to [`http.listen`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) which `express.js` used in [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L615)

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

> If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections on any IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise.

Comment: but why does it return blank? Shouldn't it be an IP address of some sort?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, the result is `http://:::3000`, and the `::` is the IP address of `IPV6`, not _blank_ I think.

Comment: In  the past, it works fine showing http://127.0.0.1:3000 but, after some days, it stopped and never showed again :(

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, the `http.listen` doc of node.js explain the `::` is used for IPV6 enabled.

Comment: @BrennoLeal the relevant part seems to [be here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback): `If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections on any IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise. A port value of zero will assign a random port.`

Answer (score 10):

I tried the example and had the same output for hostname '::', I did the following change as a workaround:

```
 var server = app.listen(3000, 'localhost', function () {
     var host = server.address().address;
     var port = server.address().port;
     console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

output:

Example app listening at http://127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: Yes, i already did too, but it is not avaiable over the network. Did you tried to access the machine IP with another PC/smartphone/tablet?

Comment: In my example I'm setting localhost as the address so If you need it to be available to the network can you try to set your machine IP address instead of localhost and give it a try?

Comment: i did it in before come here... It works well, but in the past expressJS give us the network address automatically

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the results you are looking for. You should not need to include 'localhost'

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    require('dns').lookup(require('os').hostname(), function (err, add, fam) {
        debug('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', add, port);
    })
});
```